# How can I serialize my viewmodel without it being in a form using ajax (MVC)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which contains multiple div sections, each of which contains an Html.Partial(). I am passing a view model to this view, and I am trying to update the view model as the user progresses through each section. I have discovered a way that I can easily serialize my view model if it's in a form using (#formid).serialize().

The problem I have, though, is that I would like to serialize some sections that are not in a form. Is there any way I can serialize my view model without using a form? My goal is to update the view model on the page using ajax.

My viewmodel:

*UserPositionVM*

```
public class UserPositionVM
{
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
    public virtual Positions Position { get; set; }
    public int steplevel;

}
```

*MyView.cshtml*

```
@model ViewModels.UserPositionVM

<div class="tab-pane" id="first">
    <form id="accountForm" method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-12" id="userlookup">
            @Html.Partial("UserLookup")
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="second">
    <form id="profileForm" method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-12" id="userinfo">
            @Html.Partial("UserInfo", Model)
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="processnext()">Next</a></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var page = "@Model.steplevel";
    function processnext() {
        if (page == 0) {
            var usernum = document.getElementById('User_Number').value;
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UserInfo", "Positions")',
                data: { un: usernum },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $("#userinfo").html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else if (page == 1) {
            var formdata = $('#profileForm').serialize();
             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("EditUserInfo", "Positions")',
                 data: formdata,
                 type: "POST",
                 success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $("#userinfo").html(data);
                    }
                 }
             });
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem I am having is with my first function. I want to change this:

```
var usernum = document.getElementById('User_Number').value;
$.ajax({
    data: { un: usernum }
```

To something like this:

```
var viewmodel = myviewmodel.serialize()
$.ajax({
    data: viewmodel
```

How can I do this without putting my model in a form? All I have seen on stack overflow is posts on how to serialize a form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method example:

```
var yourModel = '@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)';
console.log(yourModel);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, I am getting a self-referencing loop error when I try this. I'm currently reading this article (https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/) to see if I can resolve it. Could there be any different approach to passing my view model back to the controller?

Comment: @nightmare637 try like this: var yourModel = '@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore })';